# confusion about volume of cubes

Tags: geometry

cubes are placed in a tray with length 11, width 6 and height 5. Each cube has an edge of 2 cm. Find the maximum number of cubes that can be placed in the tray. How would i knew whether to round off 11 to 10 or 12 and 5 to 4 or 6?

Comment: I think the assumption is that for an ice cube to be "within the tray" means that it must lie entirely inside the $11 \times 6 \times 5$ rectangular prism. Does that help you decide which way to round?

Answer (score 2):

The length of the tray is 11 cm. Will 5 of these 2 cm cubes fit in that 11 cm length? Will 6 cubes fit?

The height of the tray is 5 cm. Will 2 of these 2 cm cubes fit in that 5 cm height? Will 3 cubes fit?